# What to use instead of initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier:

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates

I have watched the Lynda iPhone tutorials and on the lesson about Tableviews there is a method to create a cell as follows.

```
//create cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableView alloc]
                         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                         reuseIdentidier:@"cell"];
```

but Xcode says there is no such method. as well as obviously no code sense picking it up.

What method can be used instead of the above?  thanks /

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example contains an error:

Use [[**UITableViewCell** alloc]... instead [[**UITableView** alloc]...